# How do i use a function in query builder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a function called getValue which used to get a string value from a table in database and it has 3 parameters

```
public static function getValue($entityId, $itemId, $langId){
    $value = EntityLocalization::select('value')
            ->where('entity_id' ,'=', $entityId)
            ->where('item_id', '=', $itemId)
            ->where('lang_id', '=', $langId)->first();   
    return $value;
}
```

how do i use this function in a query builder and give its parameters from records value.
Here is the query builder in a controller its wrong

```
      $data['products'] = DB::table('products')
                                    ->join('entity_localizations', 'entity_localizations.item_id', '=', 'products.id')
                                    ->select('products.id as id',DB::raw('ifnull(entity_localizations.value ,products.name) as name'),
                                    'products.photo as photo','products.price as price',
                                    getValue(1, 'products.product_epartment_id',1) 
                                    ->where('entity_localizations.entity_id', '=', 1)
                                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getValue` function is a `static` function you should call the function by its relative class-name `YourClassName::getValue(1, 'products.product_epartment_id',1)` or you can use `self` keyword (`self::getValue(1, 'products.product_epartment_id',1)`) if function is in the same class where you are using query.

Also this function should return a single string and valid column value if you are using it's return value as a parameter of `select` function.

Answer (score 0):

use the following

eloquent: `selectRaw(getValue(...) . ' as someColumnName')`

otherwise: `DB::raw();`

Comment: i used selectRaw but i got an error Call to undefined function selectRaw() ?

Comment: Right, selectRaw is probably an eloquent method.. the equivalent would be `\DB::raw();`

Answer (score 0):

The value you're trying to use probably doesn't match the table field name.

As Rohit wrote, you should return a string instead, also you could use `firstOrfail()` to throw a more precise exception. Then you'll find out if you're getting null instead of an actual value.

```
return EntityLocalization
  ::where('entity_id' ,'=', $entityId)
  ->where('item_id', '=', $itemId)
  ->where('lang_id', '=', $langId)
  ->firstOrFail()
  ->value;
```

Debug by either dumping query `->toSql()` or simply look at the result and check your database. Ensure that the value you're getting actual corresponds with the table schema.